# How to hide cPanel directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a server that uses cPanel.

There is a built-in feature with cPanel where I can access the login area by going to domain.com/cpanel.

I was wondering if there was a way to disable it or hide it. I've tried creating a cpanel directory with an index.html file.

Comment: Do you have access to WHM?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to WHM.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you're running the linux version, not the FreeBSD or windows versions (if so just let me know).

Log into your server (shell, not through whm) and open

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search for -

```
ServerAlias cpanel.* whm.* webmail.* webdisk.*
```

Change it to -

```
ServerAlias whm.* webmail.* webdisk.*
```

Then just restart apache-

```
/scripts/restartsrv_apache
```